# Using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web without Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am trying to build a dotnet core web app on a build server that has MsBuild, but not Visual Studio, installed. I cannot get around the message **error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.**

The command dotnet --info shows Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 installed, just as on my development machine where the project builds. The contents of C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100 appear to match between the two machines. Global.json points to the 3.1.0 version.

1. Is Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web a separately-installed thing? I see what look like separate packages, now deprecated, on NuGet, and I'm guessing this is now baked into the base .NET SDK?
2. Where should I be looking for differences to try to find the missing pieces?

Comment: Use `dotnet --list-sdks` to make sure the SDK is installed and not just the runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The SDKs are present, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by (1) running vs-buildtools installer to put some additional pieces in place, and (2) adding some NuGet packages for web component.